# Performance of "NOT IN" in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm quite new to SQL query analysis. Recently I stumbled upon a performance issue with one of the queries and I'm wondering whether my thought process is correct here and why Query Optimizer works the way it works in this case. 
I'm om SQL Server 2012.
I've got a SQL query that looks like

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
WHERE Id NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT T1_Id from T2);
```

It takes around 30 seconds to run on my test server.
While trying to understand what is taking so long I rewrote it using a temp table, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1_Id 
INTO #temp from T2;
SELECT * FROM T1 
WHERE Id NOT IN  
(SELECT T1_Id from #temp);
```

It runs a hundred times faster than the first one.

Some info about the tables: 
T2 has around 1 million rows, and there are around 1000 distinct values of T1_id there. T1 has around 1000+ rows. Initially I only had a clustered index on T2 on a column other than T1_Id, so T1_id wasn't indexed at all.

Looking at the execution plans, I saw that for the first query there were as many index scans as there are distinct T1_id values, so basically SQL Server performs about 1000 index scans in this case. 
That made me realize that adding a non-clustered index on T1_id may be a good idea (the index should've been there from the start, admittedly), and adding an index indeed made the original query run much faster since now it does nonclustered index seeks.

What I'm looking for is to understand the Query optimizer behavior for the original query - does it look reasonable? Are there any ways to make it work in a way similar to the temporary table variant that I posted here rather than doing multiple scans? Am I just misunderstanding something here? 
Thanks in advance for any links to the similar discussion as I haven't really found anything useful.

Comment: [You should try `NOT EXISTS`](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: NOT EXISTS works the same way for the first query - i.e. there are as many executions of index scan/seek as there are unique values of T1_Id

Comment: that's great, but it only works when you know the not in column is not nullable. Not exists doesn't fall into that trap, so why use not in when it's only safe in some cases, instead of not exists when it is always safe? As for what's going on in this case, please show the actual plans (.sqlplan files, not a screenshot please).

Answer (score 2):

Not in is intuitive but slow. This construct will generally run quicker.

```
where id in 
(select id from t1
except select t1_id from t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual performance will likely vary from the estimates, but neither of your queries will out-perform this query, which is the de facto standard approach:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.Id = T2.T1_Id
WHERE T2.T1_Id IS NULL
```

This uses a proper join, which will perform very well (assuming the foreign key column is indexed) and being an *left* (outer) join the `WHERE` condition selects only those rows from `T1` that *don't* join (all columns of the right side table are `null` when the join misses).

Note also that `DISTINCT` is not required, since there is only ever *one* row returned from `T1` for missed joins.

Comment: This pattern is actually very expensive compared to NOT IN / NOT EXISTS. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Aaron, great article, I actually read it before posting here. What would be your preferred way of writing this with NOT IN/NOT EXISTS? Should intermediate temp table be used in this case then to avoid multiple index seeks?

Comment: @AlexSh no idea, we'd have to actually see the actual execution plans to understand why it's slower to use exists. You know you don't need the distinct (which potentially adds an unnecessary sort), right?

Comment: @AaronBertrand This pattern performs just fine. And unlike `NOT IN`, it's also simple and scaleable. So there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did (just) read your link. It says this is "OK". However, the efficiency of this query increases as the number of resulting rows (ie the number of missed joins) increases. So, IMHO the "best" query depends on the nature of the query conditions. If there are few rows in the results, `NOT IN ()` would probably do very well. If there are hundreds, the outer join should perform comparatively well, maybe better. However, technically what I have just said is all "hot air", so I'll run some tests on SQLFiddle and see what happens and post back. I'd like to know what works best where.

Comment: FWIW, in my case and with my data profile ( T2 has around 1 million rows, and there are around 1000 distinct values of T1_id there. T1 has around 1000+ rows) AND if T1_id is not indexed, left join works tens times faster than NOT EXISTS. With index on T1_id both work fast. Regarding the query plans: the problem that I see (at least I think it's a problem) is that NOT EXISTS (as well as NOT IN) query does N scans of T2, where N equals number of unique values of T1_id. So without nonclustered index, it ends up with a 1000 scans of 1 million row clustered index.

Comment: @alexsh that defies every single test I've ever run. Can you share your table structure on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @AaronBertrand FWIW, in my experience left join version works consistently well, and `not in ()` and `not exists()` totally suck for performance, as in minutes long execution times.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, can we please quit the grunt match (other words actually thought).  I too agree with Bohemian and find that MORE OFTEN THAN NOT, a left-join and NULL test has become more efficient, and simple...

Comment: @DRapp I'd just love to see some more evidence (like that which I supplied to the contrary) rather than "So there."

Comment: Hi gentlemen! I just got some time on my hands to finally post the tables structure. I'm new to SQLFiddle, so please let me know if that's what you expect: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e045. I changed SQL Server uniqueidentifier to char(38), not sure if that makes a difference. So what I constantly see is that JOIN version works much better with this table structure, especially if there is no index on T1_ID (it should be there, of course, but the difference in speed is very clear when it's not there). I will upload .sqlplan as well, as it seems to be a somewhat interesting issue

Comment: here is a link to "not in" and "join" query plans;  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ur5mafy3osr4mm4/not_in.sqlplan and https://www.dropbox.com/s/72u2yzh3z4v3eqm/join.sqlplan. Notes: there is NO index on t1_id in T2; T2 has around 150k rows in these plans and there are around 1000 unique t1_id values; I tested the same queries on a table with ~1 mln records with similar results.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server optimizer needs to understand the size if tables for some of its decisions.

When doing a `NOT IN` with a subquery, those estimates may not be entirely accurate.  When the table is actually materialized, the count would be highly accurate.

I think the first would be faster with an index on

```
Table2(t1_id)
```

Comment: I agree with you regarding the index, I mentioned in the OP that I ended up adding it. As for the table size - could you please clarify what do you mean by "materialized table"? Is it something I as a DB user can do?

Comment: "Materialize" is just a fancy way of saying the a table or intermediate table is created.  By the way, the "distinct" is not needed in an "in" subquery.

Comment: Thanks for that, I see. So basically there is no way to change the optimizer behavior in this case without rewriting the query? I would suspect it's quite a usual case with NOT IN, NOT EXISTS and similar operations?

Comment: There is a way with an explicit join.  This problem is usually that the optimizer chooses nested loop joins, and a hint can avoid that.  Surprisingly (to me), I haven't faced this issue on "in" subqueries, so I don't know if the hint will work directly on the query (rewriting for a left outer join is easy).

Answer (score 0):

*This is just a guess, but hopefully an educated one...*

The DBMS probably concluded that searching a large table small number of times is faster than searching a small table large number of times. That's why you had ~1000 searches on `T2`, instead of ~1000000 searches on `T1`.

When you added an index on `T2.T1_Id`, that turned ~1000 table scans (or full clustered index scans if the table is clustered) into ~1000 index seeks, which made things much faster, as you already noted.

I'm not sure why it didn't attempt a hash join (or a merge join after the index was added) - perhaps it had stale statistics and badly overestimated the number of distinct values?

One more thing: is there a FOREIGN KEY on `T2.T1_Id` referencing `T1.Id`? I know Oracle can use FKs to improve the accuracy of cost estimates (in this case, it could infer that the cardinality of `T2.T1_Id` cannot be greater than `T1.Id`). If MS SQL Server does something similar, and the FK is missing (or is [untrusted](http://shaunjstuart.com/archive/2012/11/the-importance-of-trust/)), that could contribute to the MS SQL Server thinking there are more distinct values than there really are.

*(BTW, it would have helped if you posted the actual query plans and the database structure.)*